# requires a peer of eslint

Tags: node.js

При команде `npm install` возникает ошибка:

> E:\react-dataflow-example-master>npm install
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.17 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\escodegen\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\handlebars\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\istanbul-api\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\istanbul-lib-source-maps\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\istanbul-reports\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\jest\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\jest-haste-map\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\jsdom\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\node-libs-browser\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\node-notifier\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\sane\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\handlebars\node_modules\uglify-js\package.json'
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react-dataflow-example-master\node_modules\istanbul-reports\node_modules\uglify-js\package.json'
>
> npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2 requires a peer of eslint@^3.16.1 but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN eslint-loader@1.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <4.0.0 but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 3.x but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@4.0.0 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || 3.x but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@6.4.1 requires a peer of eslint@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.

Как выправить?

Comment: Сорри если не понял вопроса. Так ось то у Вас какая ? Винда ? Там через инсталлер:  Windows Computers

Get the MSI. npm is in it.  https://github.com/npm/npm#fancy-windows-install

Comment: npm стоит, проект скачан с github'а (https://medium.com/devschacht/redux-step-by-step-e6c42a9b00cd). Большинство пакетов ставится, а на этих - ошибка.

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. От слова "warning".

Comment: Ох, спасибо. До этого не запускалась, пока не поставил eslint отдельно.